# Web application using Tapestry and Hibernate throws Exception when calling persist()

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jboss, tapestry

I'm trying to set up a web application using JBoss and Hibernate, but I can't get the SQL database running, encountering several problems.

My main problem is that when calling *persist()* Hibernate tries to insert an empty object into my table, the log is starting with this exception:

```
12:39:26,985 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
12:39:26,986 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
12:39:26,987 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000319: Could not get database metadata: java.sql.SQLException: You cannot set autocommit during a managed transaction!
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.setJdbcAutoCommit(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:888)
```

After using Google I couldn't really figure out how to solve it, but my application continues running. Somewhere after this Hibernate seems to try to call *persist()* to a created object.

```
12:39:27,202 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Hibernate: 
12:39:27,202 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)     insert 
12:39:27,203 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)     into
12:39:27,203 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)         Person
12:39:27,203 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)         (id, birthdate, gender, name, password) 
12:39:27,204 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)     values
12:39:27,204 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)         (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Using Logger I saw that this *Person* object is correctly created, but as you can see Hibernate sees the values as (null, ?, ?, ?, ?).

After this this exception is thrown:

```
12:39:27,218 ERROR [org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10031 table: PERSON column: ID
```

So then, my persistence.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="facePlace">
<non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/facePlace</non-jta-data-source>
<class>webtech2.faceplace.entities.Person</class>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

The relevant code is:

```
@Inject
@Persistence
EntityManager em;

public boolean signUp(String name,
      String password,
      String repeatPassword,
      Date birthdate,
      String gender) {
if (!password.equals(repeatPassword)) {
  return false;
}

log.info("person data: " + name + " " + password + " " + repeatPassword + " " + birthdate.toString() + " " + gender);

String saltedPassword = hashText + password;
String hashedPassword = generateHash(saltedPassword);
em.getTransaction().begin();
Person xperson = new Person(name, hashedPassword, birthdate, gender);
em.persist(xperson);
em.getTransaction().commit();
return true;
}
```

My entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

private String name;
private Date birthdate;
private long id;
private String password;
private String gender;
private Set<Person> friends;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public long getId() {
  return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
  this.id = id;
}
```

So I'm not an expert with all this, someone sees some shit in there?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your primary key is not being set when hibrenate saves the file. the @Id column in your @Entity should specify a primary key generation strategy, rather than leaving @GeneratedValue without any paramaters and having hibernate trying to pick a default generation startegy.

If you are using an identity column in the database you set.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="pkey")
    private Integer pkey;
```